# Using PHP Functions to get database values

Tags: php, function, mysqli

So i have here a function that i created. It worked when i used a postgres database but once i switched over to mysqli, for some reason, it doesn't return the id. Here is my function:

```
function getAccID($connection, $username){
    $res = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT accounts_id FROM people WHERE people.username ='$username'");
    if ($res){
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
        if ($row){
            return ($row[0]);
        }
    }else{
        //handle the error
    }

}
```

And here is how i declare the function:

```
$accountID = getAccID($connection, $user);
$p->addContent("Account ID: $accountID");
if (!$accountID) $p->addContent('Error: ' . mysqli_error($connection) . "<br>");
```

PS: If anyone says anything about me using mysqli_query instead of prepare statements, i will murder some babies :L. I'm using it to test, and once everything works, it's easy to switch to prepared statements.

### FIXED

Problem with this was with Postgres i could use the id of the fields, but with mysqli, i have to use the name.

Therefore this will not work

```
$row[0];
```

It'll have to be:

```
$row["name_of_field"];
```

Comment: (If you are going to "test" something, why not test the actual something that will be used?)

Comment: because i like to test as i go along. It's just the way i work.

Comment: and it's easier to test with queries than it is with prepared statements.

Comment: (If you're going to switch to something else, you're not testing it; this is an inappropriate mock scenario.)

Comment: I'm not here to fight a query vs prepared battle. I'm asking a question and would like it answered, not to have someone argue to me about right and wrong.

Comment: Anyway, 1) *do something* in "handle the error" and; 2) verfify the result of [`mysqli_fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) is what you think it is - i.e. that there *are* results and that you're returning the desired value within said row (I see a suspicious-looking `if`, not a traditional `while`, and no `$row["accounts_id"]`). As it is now, either-or could be "failing" which would result in an unexpected result - mainly, no useful return value - due to incomplete execution flow pathing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using **mysqli_fetch_assoc**

the $row should have the name of the field

**use  $row['id'] instead of $row[0]**

Comment: I literally just figured this out and was about to post the response. Haha thanks anyway.

Comment: To anyone else having this problem, this is the correct answer.